# Wordpress - A single css class, in a child theme stylesheet, not being invoked

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a button. I've added this to the child's style.css (child of twentytwelve)

```
.mybutton {
  background-color: #F7931E; /* orange */
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

and this within a custom html widget in a sidebar

```
<a class="mybutton"  href="blahblahblah">Online Community</a>
```

but when I view the page, the link shows just as text, not a button.

I can see via DevTools (in Chrome) that the child style sheet IS being loaded and its classes ARE being applied to other elements, but it's just not applying the button one!! The class doesn't show up at all.
If I add a new style rule for the mybutton class in DevTools, and copy and paste the css from above, the button shows up correctly, so it's not an error in the css itself.

I've tried deactivating all the other plugins, as a google search indicated that could be a cause, but that didn't help.

Any ideas on how to further debug this????

Thanks!!
Julie

Comment: Your CSS is valid, and your HTML should work. If that file *is* being loaded, and that *is* the markup being put in your Custom HTML Widget, then you've got a few possibilities.

1) You have a CSS error *above* that line in your CSS
2) You have multiple "class" attributes on your button (possibly added by poor JS/runtime find/replace PHP)
3) You have another typo somewhere

There's a couple others, but those are the most likely. I'd suspect #1 to be the most probable cause.

Comment: Thanks so much. I ran the CSS through a linter, and found no errors. After more mucking about, I ended up moving the .mybutton css further down in the file, and now it works, and I have no idea why ... bloody weird! Thanks again for your ideas.

Comment: @julielawrence that probably means that there is a bracket or semicolumn missing where your class class was declared before